# Using switch case construct will i be able to go to a function

Tags: c#

Given the following code snippet:

```
case "add":
   goto add();
   return;
case "subtract":
    goto subtract();
    return;
case "multiply":
   goto multiply();
   return;
case "division":
   goto divide();
   return;
default:
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice"):
     }
     break;
```

Using `switch case` would I be able to use the `goto` keyword to take me to the function I want? If not, how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Although the question is simple, I don't think it deserves downvotes? He asks two legible questions.

Comment: this would be a good scenario for an `enum`, btw - just saying

Comment: @SamLeach OP obviously didn't look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx), the first example shows exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: Henry, do your best to forget all about the "goto" while your at it, you will not find many reasons to use it

Comment: I strongly advise against goto programming models. In my .net experiencing, I never used it once.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the `goto` keyword, just call the method.

So

```
string methodName = Foo.GetMethodNameToCall();

      switch(methodName)
      {
          case "add":
               add();
               break;
          case "subtract":
                subtract();
                break;
          case "multiply":
               multiply();
               break;
          case "division":
               divide();
               break;
          default:
              {
                   Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice"):
                   break;
              }
       }
```

You probably want to use `break` instead of `return` in your cases also.

Comment: How to do it ? Please help

Comment: "you don't need" -- a better way to describe this is "you *cannot*". "1.6.6 goto

The goto statement transfers program execution to some label within the program. " -- [Eric Huss' *C Library Reference Guide*](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/)